# c# windows phone 8 how to add style to a button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

how can I set the style in app.xaml to my button in c# ?

**there is a style for buttons in app.xaml and I want to use it in my button in c#.**

here is my code for the button.

```
 Button deleteButton = new Button();
 deleteButton.Background = new ImageBrush
                                        {
                                            ImageSource ="Delete2.png"
                                        };
 deleteButton.Height = 70;
 deleteButton.Width = 70;
 deleteButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
 deleteButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
 deleteButton.Margin = new Thickness(0,10,0,-5);
 deleteButton.BorderBrush = null;
 deleteButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
 deleteButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ItemDeleteButton_Click);
 deleteButton.Tag = tag;
 deleteButton.Style = ?????????????????
```

Comment: If you want to use XAML for the markup, then why do you set all the markup properties from the backend code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
deleteButton.Style =  App.Current.Resources["StyleKey"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FindResource` or `TryFindResource`.

[Resources and Code - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752326.aspx)

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but it'd be better if you didn't just link to content and instead explained what should actually be done.  (See [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more suggestions...)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
deleteButton.Style = App.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Style` is probably defined in a `ResourceDictionary` elsewhere in your application.  You can retrieve that using the `FindResource` method:

```
deleteButton.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("MyCustomButtonStyle");
```